# All gtk4-rs examples failing to load system theme CSS

Tags: linux, user-interface, rust, gtk, themes

I am using the [`gtk-rs`](https://gtk-rs.org/) crate for my project. This question probably belongs on SuperUser or another site, but I am asking here because the issue only occurs with Rust projects, therefore is related to an issue with the environment used for development.

Whenever running any of the GTK4 [examples](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/tree/master/examples), a window with a transparent background is opened, with a message about a missing CSS file being printed.

```
(basics:173807): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:04:42.544: Theme parser error: gtk.css:1:1-66: Failed to import: The resource at “/org/gnome/arc-theme/gtk-main-dark.css” does not exist
```

[image: transparent_screenshot]

This issue only occurs with GTK4, and I thought perhaps the theme was missing support. However, the [files are there](https://github.com/jnsh/arc-theme/tree/master/common/gtk-4.0) and [are being compiled](https://github.com/spikespaz/arc-themes-blackish-maia/blob/master/PKGBUILD#L211).

I am running Manjaro Cinnamon with many customizations, including a patched version of the [`arc-themes-solid-maia`](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/packages/community/themes/arc-themes-maia/-/blob/master/PKGBUILD) package. That patch can be found [here](https://github.com/spikespaz/arc-themes-blackish-maia/blob/master/PKGBUILD), though I believe it to be irrelevant because I have tested with Mark Wagie's original and the same issue is present.